# Selenium Webdriver 4.9.1 python: send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+Keys.ENTER) to a identified XPATH element not working

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, sendkeys

I want to Open an element in a new tab on a web page with selenium webdriver in python,  the program says that: element is not interable,
OBS: in chrome control + enter open an link_text that you is aiming in a new tab, but i want to do this in Selenium or other method to open an element in a new tab.

the element is an xpath type with value like: "/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/main/section[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/button"
i tried that:
element_identified.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+Keys.ENTER)

Comment: Can we please get a [mcve]?